# Как подключить SearchView и RxBinding?

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid

Здравствуйте. В Toolbar находится поисковый виджет(SearchView). Необходимо реализовать следующий функционал: Пользователь в тулбаре наживает на значок лупы и открывается поле для ввода поискового запроса.Пользователь вводит некий запрос, и если после ввода символа пользователь ничего не вводит более x секунд то на сервер отправляется запрос. Я для этой цели использую связку rxjava и rxBinding.
Вот как это делается: RxTextView.textChanges(editText), т.е в метод textChanges надо передать ссылку на EditText, но как у  SearchView получить ссылку на поле ввода? и как отслеживать появление и исчезновение этого поля для подписывания и отписывания rx?

Comment: Вроде сёрчВью расширяет эдитТект

Comment: используйте RxSearchView